# Rails: form_for routes won't display a good form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

i'm new to Rails 3 and am stuck with something i think is simple to solve.
I was following the examples from Head First: Rails but came to the conclusion that they are using rails 2.

I made an html.erb file like this:

```
<h1>New user</h1>
<% form_for(@user, :url=>{:action=>'create'}) do |f| %>
  <p>Fullname: <%= f.text_field :fullname%></p>
  <p>Username: <%= f.text_field :username%></p>
  <p>Email: <%= f.text_field :email%></p>
  <p>Password: <%= f.text_field :password%></p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Create" %></p>
<% end %>
```

and i want to show this form show up when i go to http://localhost:3000/users/new so i added a route like this:

```
resources :users
match "users/new" => "users#new"
match "users/create" => "users#create"
```

When i go to the address, it show's a web page with a H1-header: New User, but it doesn't show any of the other things.

What did i forget?

Answer (score 5):

`resources :users` already contains

```
match "users/new" => "users#new"
match "users/create" => "users#create"
```

So you can safely remove them. Form doesn't display, because if you want to display result of excecution ruby code, than you should use following construction `<%= %>`. `<% %>` stands for only code execution, not for displaying.

So your new view should be like this

```
<h1>New user</h1>
<%= form_for(@user, :url=>{:action=>'create'}) do |f| %>
  <p>Fullname: <%= f.text_field :fullname%></p>
  <p>Username: <%= f.text_field :username%></p>
  <p>Email: <%= f.text_field :email%></p>
  <p>Password: <%= f.text_field :password%></p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Create" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

In rails 3 you need to use `<%= form_for`

[form_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)